# how to display asciimath equation in displaystyle (MathJax)

Tags: javascript, equation, mathjax

I 'm trying to display an AsciiMath formula in display mode, but whatever I try its still inline

Here is my MathJax configuration:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    AsciiMath: {
        fixphi: true,
        useMathMLspacing: true,
        displaystyle: true,
        decimalsign: "."
    },
    extensions: ['asciimath2jax.js'],
    jax: ['input/TeX', 'input/AsciiMath', 'output/HTML-CSS']
});
```

And the HTML

```
<p>Once upon a time ... <span>`f(x) = x^2`</span> which ... </p>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfrrf/31/)
As you can see the Latex formula `$$f(x) = x^2$$` is in display style which is what I'm looking for. So, the question is, why is the config option `displaystyle: true` not working ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AsciiMath does not have a built-in way to do this, i.e., generate `<math>` elements with `display="block"` (and thus neither does MathJax).

The `displaystyle` setting adds `displaystyle="true"` to the math. As per [the MathML spec](http://www.w3.org/Math/draft-spec/chapter2.html#interf.toplevel) `display="block"` entails `displaystyle="true"` but not vice versa; the main difference is that the former is set as block element while displaystyle controls the layout behavior (so you can choose that independently).

In [this MathJax User discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/CvM6tE0m3Rg) you can find some code to add additional delimiters; this would probably fit well on the [MathJax Third Party extensions repo](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-third-party-extensions).